# Align multiple items on each row

Tags: align, auto-multiple-choice

I'm trying to improve this [image: this], so that A,B,C,D properly aligned on each row.

I'm currently using \begin{tabular}{ p{0.5cm} | p{17cm} } to create the vertical line, but I'm willing to change that, if there's a better way.

PS: This is the really bad way of writing that the current version has:

```
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.5cm} | p{17cm}  }
\textbf{5p} & \textbf{1.} Aria triunghiului care are varfurile $A(0,0)$, $B(2,3)$, $C(-4,2)$  este:  
\newline A. $\displaystyle\frac{5}{9} $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     B. 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   C. 8\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   D. 2
 \\
  \textbf{5p} & \textbf{2.} Ecuatia tangentei la graficul functiei $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=(x+1)^2+2$ in $x_0=0$ este:
  \newline A. 2x+3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   B. $x^2+2x+3$  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \    C. 3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   D. $2x^2+1$\\
  \textbf{5p} & \textbf{3.} Daca $x_1, x_2$ sunt solutiile ecuatiei $x^2+3x+1=0$, atunci $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1\cdot x_2$ este:
  \newline A. 8 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \      B. 7  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     C. 9 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \    D. 6 \\
  \textbf{5p} & \textbf{4.} Multimea solutiilor reale ale inecuatiei $\displaystyle\frac{2x+3}{x^2+x+1}\geq 1$ este:
\newline A. $(-\infty, -1)$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \    B. $[2, +\infty)$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   C. $[-1,2]$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   D.$(-\infty, -1]\cup [2, +\infty)$ \\
  \textbf{5p} & \textbf{5.}Se considera punctele $C(-3,2)$ si $D(1,4)$. Lungimea vectorului $\overrightarrow{\rm CD}    $ este: 
  \newline A. $2\sqrt{2}$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \      B. $2\sqrt{2}$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   C. 8\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   D. 20\\
  \textbf{5p} & \textbf{6.} Valoarea expresiei $E=\sin^{2} 40^{\circ}+\sin^{2} 50^{\circ}$ este:
  \newline A. -1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \      B. 2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   C. 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   D. 1 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Make 5 columns instead of two.  Put each answer inside its own cell.  Make each question span four columns using the `\multicolumn` command.

Comment: For the first column  with the help of `array` package you can define column with `>{\bfseries}p{0.5cm}` to avoid inserting `\textbf` in every cell.

Comment: What do you mea by ‘properly aligned’, exactly?

Comment: By properly aligned I meant I wanted all the A's to be on the same vertical line, all the B's on a different one and henceforth. James' solution works great: [image](http://i.imgur.com/KFdzvZq.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each answer in its own cell and place the questions inside a `\multicolumn`.  Also, you might want to add an empty row between questions to better separate the items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|llll}
5p & \multicolumn{4}{p{17cm}}{1. Aria triunghiului care are varfurile $A(0,0)$, $B(2,3)$, $C(-4,2)$  este:} \\
& A. $\displaystyle\frac{5}{9}$ & B. 1 & C. 8 & D. 2 \\
& & & & \\
5p & \multicolumn{4}{p{17cm}}{2. Ecuatia tangentei la graficul functiei $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=(x+1)^2+2$ in $x_0=0$ este:} \\
& A. 2x+3 & B. $x^2+2x+3$ & C. 3 & D. $2x^2+1$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]